# iOS How To Convert Dictionary<String, Any> to query params which containing array

Tags: arrays, swift

I Have a Dictionary Data:

```
let dict: [String: Any] = [
    "shapeIDs": [1,2,3],
    "rows": [1,2],
    "userID": "231"
]
```

I want to convert it in query params for URL. My Expect Result should be this:

```
"?shapeIDs[]=1&shapeIDs[]=2&shapeIDs[]=3&rows[]=1&rows[]=2&userID=231"
```

Please help to create an optimistic logic for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I Tried this:

extension Dictionary {
    var queryString: String? {
        let query = self.reduce("") { (result, keyValue) -> String in
            var string = ""
            if let values = keyValue.value as? Array<Any> {
                string = values.map({"\(keyValue.key)[]=\($0)&"}).reduce("", +)
            } else {
                string = "\(keyValue.key)=\(keyValue.value)&"
            }
            return result + string
        }.dropLast()
        return String(query)
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

Swift Solution:

```
extension Dictionary {
    var queryString: String {
        let query = self.reduce("") { (result, keyValue) -> String in
            var string = ""
            if let values = keyValue.value as? Array<Any> {
                string = values.map({"\(keyValue.key)[]=\($0)&"}).reduce("", +)
            } else {
                string = "\(keyValue.key)=\(keyValue.value)&"
            }
            return result + string
        }.dropLast()
        return "?" + String(query)
    }
}
```

Comment: query it is already a string. No need to initialize another string. Bye no need to return an optional string if you never return nil

Comment: @LeoDabus using dropFirst we get data in String.SubSequence, so it needs to convert into String.

Comment: @GurjitSingh What's the problem in the solution you've provided yourself?

Comment: @GurjitSingh You are adding it to a string so you don't need to convert it to string

Comment: Btw one liner `"?" + reduce("") { result, keyValue in result + ((keyValue.value as? [Int])?.map({"\(keyValue.key)[]=\($0)&"}).joined() ?? "\(keyValue.key)=\(keyValue.value)&") }.dropLast()`

Comment: @LeoDabus please try one time in your Xcode playground please.